# Haskell: <- in do notation for monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I see the following example from [**Writer**](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#writer) section in learn you a haskell.

```
    import Control.Monad.Writer  

    logNumber :: Int -> Writer [String] Int  
    logNumber x = Writer (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x])  

    multWithLog :: Writer [String] Int  
    multWithLog = do  
        a <- logNumber 3  
        b <- logNumber 5  
        return (a*b)
```

The result is:

```
    ghci> runWriter multWithLog  
    (15,["Got number: 3","Got number: 5"])
```

I know that in do notation **<-** will extract the value from the context. so **a** and **b** should be tuples with format **(Int, [String])** according to **Writer**'s declaration. I feel **a** and **b** should be two integers in **return (a*b)**, otherwise we cannot do multiplication.

What is my misunderstanding here? Can someone help? Many thanks.

Comment: You already know: "I know that in do notation `<-` will **extract** the value from the context." (Emphasis added) Yes, it extracts the value from the context, so the monad context (here roughly [String]) is not included in the `x` of `x <- ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main "work" in monads is produced in **>>=** (bind) function.
Monads are some sort of computation builders. So if you want to know how computations happens in concrete Monad, you need to open implementation of it's **>>=** and **return** funcs.

E.g. Writer's monad [implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/src/Control-Monad-Writer-Lazy.html#Writer):

```
instance (Monoid w) => Monad (Writer w) where
    return a = Writer (a, mempty)
    m >>= k  = Writer $ let
        (a, w)  = runWriter m
        (b, w') = runWriter (k a)
        in (b, w `mappend` w')
```

So it takes another writer **m**, get it's computation results **a** (Int in your case) and additional context **w** ([String]) by executing runWriter on it. Then it feeds result to function **k** that returns another Writer. After getting the result, it combines to **contexts** by applying **mappend** which in case of list is **++**.

So composition of Strings occurs in **w `mappend` w'**. All this happens behind the scenes.

As you can see, **>>=** feeds to function **k** only the result **a** (Int), without any context([String]). That's why you don't have any pairs in you code.

Maybe if you rewrite your code without "do" syntactic sugar it will be more clear:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer
logNumber :: Int -> Writer [String] Int 
logNumber x = Writer (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x])  
multWithLog =
    logNumber 3 >>=
    \a -> logNumber 5 >>=
    \b -> return (a*b)
```

Comment: I understand your point. My further question is how `return` knows `["Got number: 3","Got number: 5"]` should be contained in the `Writer` that it creates. `>>=` feeds to function `k` only the result `a` without any context, so I have no idea why `return` knows what to do.

Comment: `return` knows nothing about previous context or something. All `return` does is that he create Writer with empty context ([] in this case). So `return a*b` creates Writer (a*b) []. But because we chain actions using `>>=`, we get such concatenation in the end.

Look at the code in `>>=`, we store previous context in `w` and concatenate it with new one - `w'`.
After first action `w = ["Got: 3"]`, and `w'` - context of the rest action. What it equals? Do next step: `w = ["Got: 5"]` and `w' = []` resulting in: `["Got: 5"] ++ [] = ["Got: 5"]`. Now return to previous : ["Got: 3"] ++ ["Got: 5"].

Comment: The main key - return doesn't do something special. We need to put it in the end only to write `a*b` in the result without changing a context (list ++ [] = list). You can remove it:
    `multWithLog = logNumber 3 >>= \a -> logNumber 5`

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the definition of `logNumber` for a second and just care for its signature:

```
logNumber :: Int -> Writer [String] Int
```

We know that `Writer s` is a monad (given `Monoid s`). Lets use a type synonym `StringWriter` for a second to make things clearer:

```
type StringWriter = Writer [String]
logNumber :: Int -> StringWriter Int
```

Remember, `Writer s` is a monad, and `StringWriter` is simply a type synonym to that monad. We also change the type of `multWithLog`:

```
multWithLog :: StringWriter Int
```

It should be clear now that the value wrapped in the `StringWriter` context is an `Int`, and not a pair. Now, go back to your statement:

> I know that in do notation `<-` will extract the value from the context.

And at this point it should be obvious that the value being extracted has type `Int`.

Comment: I thought `Writer` is a monad.

Comment: How does the code know to put `["Got number: 3","Got number: 5"]` in the final `return` statetment? I don't see any code passing the list of strings to the `return` statement.

Comment: No. `Writer` is a type constructor with arity 2 (that is, the `Writer` type constructor expects 2 type arguments in order to have a type). As a monad always is a type constructor of arity 1, we need first apply `Writter` to a type argument in order to get a monad. Therefore `Writer` is not a monad, but `Writer [String]` is.

Comment: `runWriter writer` runs the `writer` computation and results in the pair composed by the its return value and the final context. In your example, the computation returns 15 and the final context is `["Got number: 3","Got number: 5"]`, therefore the result is the pair `(15,["Got number: 3","Got number: 5"])`.

Comment: In `multiWithLog`, how is the list of strings passed into the final `return`? I see `return x = Writer (x, mempty)` in the monad definition of `Writer`.

Comment: @user811416 The definition of `>>=` for Writer takes care of that. You can read [the definition in LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#writer), under the heading "The Writer type". Essentially, when you extract a value, the message gets added to the list of strings. When you do `return`, it just keeps going with the previous list of strings.

Comment: Yes, I know you are talking about `logNumber 3 >>= (\a-> logNumber 5 >>=(\b-> return (a*b)))`. I have difficulty in understanding this structure. Can you please write down the detailed process?

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement, that `a` and `b` are tuples, isn't quite correct.

If we have something like

```
foo = do
  ...
  baz <- bar
  quux
```

if `bar :: m a` then we can treat `baz` as a value of type `a` in `quux` since `<-` desugars (roughly) to

```
foo = do
  ...
  bar >>= \baz -> quux
```

Answer (score 0):

Zeta [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23904704/3694224) quite nicely why `a` and `b` are `Int` and not pairs.

I think the main point of confusion stems from the last row

```
return (a*b)
```

If `a = 3` and `b = 5`, shouldn't this result in `Writer (15, [])`? Well, it does, but where does the `["Got number: 3","Got number: 5"]` come from then?

The answer lies in the implementation of `>>=`. Let's remove the syntactic sugar of the `do` notation:

```
multWithLog = do  
    a <- logNumber 3  
    b <- logNumber 5  
    return (a*b)
```

is equivalent to

```
logNumber 3 >>= (\a ->
logNumber 5 >>= (\b ->
return (a*b)))
```

is equivalent to

```
Writer (3, ["Got number: 3"]) >>= (\a ->
Writer (5, ["Got number: 5"]) >>= (\b ->
Writer (a*b, [])))
```

is equivalent to

```
Writer (3, ["Got number: 3"]) >>= (\a ->
Writer (5, ["Got number: 5"]) >>= (\b ->
Writer (3*5, [])))
```

Remember, `>>=` *is a binary function* (function that takes two arguments) that returns a `Writer (Int, [String])`, i.e. a `Writer` with an `Int` and a log. The returned log from the function `>>=` is a combination of the first argument's log `["Got number 3", "Got number 5"]` and the second argument's log `[]`.

<sup>I lied o_o</sup>
**Sidenote**: the actual order of log appending, if you look at the parentheses, will be

```
["Got number: 3"] ++ (["Got number: 5"] ++ [])
```